# ACE static highlight without using PHP tags

Tags: static, editor, ace-editor

This is an example of using ext-static-highlight.js of ACE Editor. How would I set the inline option to true, so I can avoid using PHP tags when highlighting the code?

```
<script>
var highlight = ace.require("ace/ext/static_highlight")
var dom = ace.require("ace/lib/dom")
function qsa(sel) {
    return Array.apply(null, document.querySelectorAll(sel));
}

qsa(".code").forEach(function (codeEl) {
    highlight(codeEl, {
        mode: codeEl.getAttribute("ace-mode"),
        theme: codeEl.getAttribute("ace-theme"),
        startLineNumber: 1,
        showGutter: codeEl.getAttribute("ace-gutter"),
        trim: true
    }, function (highlighted) {

    });
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass an object to the highlight function as a mode `{path: "ace/mode/php", inline: true}`.
so use something like this:

```
<script>
var highlight = ace.require("ace/ext/static_highlight")
var dom = ace.require("ace/lib/dom")
function qsa(sel) {
    return Array.apply(null, document.querySelectorAll(sel));
}

qsa(".code").forEach(function (codeEl) {
    var mode = codeEl.getAttribute("ace-mode");
    if (mode == "php-inline")
        mode = {path: "ace/mode/php", inline: true}
    highlight(codeEl, {
        mode: mode,
        theme: codeEl.getAttribute("ace-theme"),
        startLineNumber: 1,
        showGutter: codeEl.getAttribute("ace-gutter"),
        trim: true
    }, function (highlighted) {

    });
});
</script>
```